# Calling a Function to a Certain Parameter in Pygame

Tags: python, function, parameters, pygame, coordinates

I'm new to programming. I'm using python 3.4 and pygame cp34 on Windows 8. I've created this little guy and I'm seeing what I can do with it. What happens when I load this part of the code in my program (by calling the function with "guy()" in the main program loop), is that it seems to appear by default in the (0,0) parameter (upper left of the screen). According to all the instructions I've read on the internet, all I have to do is call, say, "guy(screen, 100, 100)" in the main program loop and the image should appear with the upper-left of the image starting at the 100,100 x y parameters. What happens instead is that the guy always stays in the upper-left corner of the screen at 0,0 regardless of my instructions. No error message. The instructions just get completely ignored. Is there something in my def that is preventing me from giving parameter instructions? 
Again, the guy appears if called in the main program loop, but the parameters never change from the upper-left corner of the screen.

```
import pygame


g = pygame.Color('green')
c = pygame.Color('cyan')
b = pygame.Color('brown')
w = pygame.Color('white')
r = pygame.Color('red')
o = pygame.Color('orange')
e = pygame.Color('yellow')

data = [
 [c, c, c, w, c, c, c, w, c, c, w, c, c, c, w, w, c],
 [c, c, w, w, w, c, c, w, w, c, w, w, c, w, w, w, w],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, o, o, o, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, o, o, o, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, e, c, c, g, e, g, c, c, e, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, e, c, e, e, e, c, e, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, e, c, e, c, e, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, r, r, r, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, r, r, r, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, r, r, r, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, b, c, b, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, b, c, b, c, c, c, c, c, c],
 [g, g, g, g, g, g, g, r, r, g, r, r, g, g, g, g, g],
 [g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g],
 ]

 def guy(screen, x, y):
 for y, row in enumerate(data):
     for x, color in enumerate(row):
     pic = pygame.Rect(x*5,y*5,5,5)
     screen.fill(color, pic)
```

Comment: You're overriding the inputs `x` and `y` with the return value from `enumerate`.  What happens if you change to `def guy(screen, x1, y1):` and `pic = pygame.Rect(x*5+x1,y*5+y1,5,5)`?

Comment: @zehnpaard that's it! That's the answer! Thank you so much. You have no idea how long I've been banging my head over this!

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the inputs `x` and `y` with the return value from enumerate. change to `def guy(screen, x1, y1):` and `pic = pygame.Rect(x*5+x1,y*5+y1,5,5)`